# GKVoiceChat not working on GameCenter Match

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

I'm trying to set up voice-chat on a game I'm developing for iOS, it successfully creates the match, but when I try to set up the voice-chat it does nothing, what am I doing wrong? It runs without throwing errors. Here's the code I'm using to make the voice-chat.

```
- (void)establishVoice
{
    if (![GKVoiceChat isVoIPAllowed])
        return;

    if (![self establishPlayAndRecordAudioSession])
        return;

    NSLog(@"Did stablish voice chat");

    chat = [match voiceChatWithName:@"GeneralChat"];
    [chat start]; // stop with [chat end];
    chat.active = YES; // disable mic by setting to NO
    chat.volume = 1.0f; // adjust as needed.

    chat.playerStateUpdateHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKVoiceChatPlayerState state) {
        switch (state)
        {
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerSpeaking:
                // Highlight player's picture
                NSLog(@"Speaking");
                break;
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerSilent:
                // Dim player's picture
                NSLog(@"Silent");
                break;
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerConnected:
                // Show player name/picture
                NSLog(@"Voice connected");
                break;
            case GKVoiceChatPlayerDisconnected:
                // Hide player name/picture
                NSLog(@"Voice disconnected");
            break;
        } };
}
```

Where establishPlayAndRecordAudioSession is:

```
- (BOOL) establishPlayAndRecordAudioSession
{
    NSLog(@"Establishing Audio Session");
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error setting session category: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        success = [audioSession setActive: YES error: &error];
        if (success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Audio session is active (play and record)");
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error activating audio session: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The code successfully logs "Did stablish voice chat", so it does run the code, but when I start talking, it doesn't seem to get the voice nor send it. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? P.S. I'm not getting the GKVoiceChatPlayerConnected fired.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure wifi is turned on on both devices.

(I was banging my head on this for hours, and finally realized that I'd accidentally turned wifi off on one of my 2 test devices)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If Wifi was disabled, maybe the user wouldn’t be able to create a match?